# Pullback of Constant Sheaf: A "Very Plain Proof"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $Y$ be any scheme, $S$ a set and $\underline{S}_Y$ the constant sheaf on some reasonble site over $X$, say to have something concrete in mind the small etale site $X_{\text{et}}$. Let $f: X \to Y$ any morphism of schemes.
It is well known that the pullback sheaf $f^*\underline{S}_Y$ is a constant sheaf too isomorphic to $\underline{S}_X$.

There are three arguments known to me to show it:
(1) $\underline{S}_Y$ can be realized as pullback of the constant sheaf $\underline{S}_{\text{pt}}$ with respect to a map $p_Y: Y \to \text{pt}$. Then observe that $p_X^*\mathcal{F} \cong f^*p_Y^*\mathcal{F}$ for any sheaf
(2) $\underline{S}_Y$ is represenable by etale projection $Y \times S \to Y$ and the pullback is obviously representable by etale $X \times_Y (Y \times S)= X \times S$
(3) Locally constant sheaves correspond under $\mathcal{F} \mapsto \mathcal{F}_u$ for arbitrary geometric point $y: y \to Y$ to sets with $\pi_1(Y,y)$-action by algebr fundamental group. Constant sheaves correspond to those with trivial $\pi_1(Y,y)$-action. Under this equivalence the $\pi_1(X,x)$ corresponding to the pullback $f^*\underline{S}_Y$ is given by $S$ with inducted action by composition $\pi_1(X,x)\to \pi_1(Y,y)$,

But I have to admit that I still not completely not happy with these arguments, as they appear a bit too tricky or say requires relatively too much effort for this - say nearly trivial fact. Note that no one uses explicitly the standard definition of pullback sheaf as sheafification of certain presheaf; see below.

And I'm wondering if it is not possible to show this more *"directly, or plainly without a roundabout way"* using just directly this definition of pullback sheaf that $f^*\underline{S}_Y$ is a constant sheaf instead more or less using "tricks" or refering to deeper results.
**Concern/Problem:** In other words, is there a "canonical way" to prove it working **only** with definition of pullback sheaf obtained as sheafification of the presheaf described below? In short terms, I'm looking for a " very plain" proof of this obvious plain fact.

Recall, for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ the pullback presheaf $\text{pre} f^*\mathcal{F}$ is defined for any etale $V \to X$ by

$$ \text{pre} f^*\mathcal{F}(V)= \varinjlim_U \mathcal{F}(U)  $$

where the direct limit runs over etale $U \to Y$ through which the composition $V \to X \to Y$ factors.

Now does there exist a say "straight fortward strategy" to establish that $f^*\underline{S}_Y$ is isomorphic to $\underline{S}_X$ directly using only this?

On level on stalks it's clear that $(f^*\underline{S}_Y)_{f(x)}=(f^*\underline{S}_Y)_x=S =(\underline{S}_X)_x$ and using universal property of sheafification it suffice to construct explicitly compatible maps
$ \text{pre} f^*\mathcal{F}(V) \to \underline{S}_X(V) $ on level of local sections wrt etale maps $V \to X$ which gives an iso on level of stalks.

My "naive guess" is the following: Let $U \to Y$ any etale morphism in direct system defining $ \text{pre} f^*\mathcal{F}(V) $, ie $V \to X\to Y$ factors through $U$, especially $f(V) \subset U $ on level of sets/ topolog.

$V \to X$ is etale and has $n=\pi_0(V)$ components $V_1,..., V_n$ and let $U_1,..., U_m$ be the components of $U$. Then, every $f(V_i)$ by continuity is contained in a *unique* $U_{f{V,U}(i)}$. So we obtain a well defined function $f_{U,V}:\{1,..., n\} \to \{1,..., m\}$.

If $f_{U,V}$ is surjective, then we could constuct a map $m_U(V):\underline{S}_Y(U) \to   \underline{S}_X(V)$ as follows ( and then passing to the limit over all $U$):

Let $s:=(s_1,..., s_j, ...,s_m) \in S^{\pi_0(U)}=\underline{S}_Y(U)$ with $s_j \in S $ corresponding to factor associated with $U_j$. We map this vector to the vector $t:=(t_1,..., t_k, ...,t_n) \in S^{\pi_0(V)}=\underline{S}_X(V)$ such that $t_i:= s_j$ if $j =f_{U,V}(i)$.

This should be compatible with limits so far as long as we dealing with $U \to Y$ such that $f_{U,V}$ surjective, ie every component of $U$ contains at least one component of $ f(V)$. How to extend it if that's not the case?

Modulo this problem, does this approach work? And if yes, is this the say most "canonical" approach to prove that $f^*\underline{S}_Y$ is constant using definition of pullback solely, or can be done in more sophisticated way?

Comment: I don't understand how (i) is tricky. It is extremely direct: the constant sheaf $\underline{X}$ is *by definition* the pullback of $X$ viewed as a sheaf on a point. The fact that $f^* \circ p_Y^* \cong (p_Y \circ f)^*$ is immediate from the universal property of pullbacks. $p_Y \circ f = p_X$ is direct. These are not tricks, nor are they deep results. On the contrary, expanding the construction of $f^* \underline{X}$ is an unnecessarily complicated thing to do!

Comment: I think method (1) *is* a direct approach using only the definition. The constant presheaf on $Y$ with value $A$ is *clearly* the presheaf pullback of the constant presheaf on $\mathrm{pt}$ with value $A$ (it's a filtered colimit over a constant diagram) and the presheaf pullback of this along $f$ is then the constant presheaf with value $A$ on $X$. Then apply sheafification. (Establishing that the sheafification of the presheaf pullback and the sheaf pullback of the sheafification agree requires an argument, but this is an absolutely essential fact in any case.)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I agree, that "tricky" was a wrong word in this case. The point is that in (1) (...and other presented arguments) one needs - an admittedly not a deep one - but an "idea or an observation", and when I say "a plain proof" I mean something like, "you take just given definition (of pullback) and check it simply with the head through the wall". That's what I mean by "plain". I agree that the question is a bit strange, but I was wondering why it's not possible to state this extremly plausible fact just by spelling plainly out the definition of pullback

Comment: @Thorgott: That's an interesting point which that went through my head resoning about this question! In general, so far I know sheafification **not** commutes with taking pullbacks, right? Ie if $\mathcal{P}$ is a presheaf, let denote by  $s(-)$ the "sheafification" "functor and by by $f^P$ the presheaf pullback wrt a map $f:X \to Y$. Then by definition $f^* = s(-) \circ f^P$, but in general $s(f^P (s(\mathcal{P}))) \neq s(f^P(\mathcal{P})) $, or do I missing something?

Comment: @Thorgott: See eg Milne's Etale Cohomology, Remark 2.14 (b), p 63 - the book, not the online script. But then, what do you mean by that "the sheafification of the presheaf pullback and the sheaf pullback of the sheafification agree"? Especially, what is for you the difference between "sheafification of the presheaf pullback" and "sheaf pullback"? Isn't this by def the same?

Comment: @Thorgott: The funny thing is that if this discrepance between  $s(f^P (s(\mathcal{P})))$ and $ s(f^P(\mathcal{P}))$ for *proper presheaves* $\mathcal{P}$ (ie those presheaves that are nit sheaves), isn't a discrepance at all (...so if I'm wrong and these sheaves would be indeed always isomorphic), then this would give the "plain proof" I ws looking for by just applying preshef pullbck not to the "constant sheaf", but the "constant presheaf" first.

Comment: But do you know about "how far" $s(f^P (s(\mathcal{P}))) $ might be differ from $ s(f^P(\mathcal{P}))$ if $\mathcal{P}$ is a honest presheaf?

Comment: @Thorgott: An update: my assumption that $s(f^P (s(\mathcal{P}))) \neq s(f^P(\mathcal{P}))$ in general for any presheaf $\mathcal{P}$ was plainly wrong, it holds in full generality, and so once having this, then applying this to $\mathcal{P}=S$ constant presheaf and observe that for constant presheaf $S=f^{P}S$ holds by definition, gives that kind of "plain proof" I was looking for

Comment: @user267839 Ah, I was out while you were pondering this (though it seems to have been instructive). Yes, this always holds and you can get it e.g. from the Yoneda lemma by combining the inclusion-sheafification and (presheaf) pushforward-pullback adjunctions together with the fact that the presheaf pushforward of a sheaf is already a sheaf. You can obtain an explicit isomorphism from this after unwinding (it should look simpler than what you've written in your question, but—I apologize—I don't have the time to check what you wrote in detail right now).